# Custom Landing Page Once Logged in salesforce

Tags: oauth, oauth2

I wish to create different **custom landing pages** for users based on their profile, after successful login through SalesForce. Is it possible to create? Provide your thoughts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can do this with Apps and Profiles in Salesforce.

1. Associate the custom Landing page(VF Page) to a Visualforce Tab (Create --> Tab --> New VF Tab)
2. Create an App and associate required Tabs to newly created App. (Create --> Apps)
3. Set the Default Landing page in the App settings.
4. Now go to Profiles (Manage User --> Profiles --> Custom App Settings)
5. Set the newly created app as default App.
6. Assign required users to the Profile.

Now, when users logs into Salesforce, they would be taken to default App, which is associated to VF page. Hope this helps.